# Calculate Taylor Series function and converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Calculate the Taylor series of the function $f(x) = 3/x$ about $a = 3$. 
Where (if anywhere) does the series converge to $3/x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the Taylor series you need to find the derivatives of the function and evaluate them in the point a=3:

$$\frac{d^nf}{dx^n}=3(-1)^n(n!)x^{-(n+1)}$$

The series is:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{3^n}(x-3)^n$$

The series converges, if you want to look for uniform convergence you can use the Cauchy-Hadamard criteria but in this case is simple to show that it converges for $x \neq 0$ because that's the only point in which the solution becomes unbounded.

Comment: how do you get the series? I have the pattern of F^n of (3) = 3(-1)^n(n+1)!/(n+1)3^(n+1)

Comment: I am close in getting $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{3^nn!}(x-3)^n$$ but i dont know how to do the (n+1)!/(n+1)

Comment: what i get for the series is $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n (n+1)!}{3^nn!(n+1)}(x-3)^n$$

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake calculating the series, I have just fixed it.

Comment: Yes, your last result is correct. $$(n+1)!=(n+1)(n!)$$

Comment: So, the series should be $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nn!}{3^nn!}(x-3)^n$$ ?

Comment: oh right! i saw your edited answer. and yup that's what i got. cheers!